# A problem in integration .XBAP with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xbap

When I run the .XBAP in an ASP.NET project as the following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx

p.s :i put the .XBAP and .exe files in 3 places ( bin, main project folder and a new folder )

the Like takes me to a page said
( An error occurred in the application you were using
You can try the following:
Restart the application. 
Click the "More Information" link below for details about this error. 
 More Information )

Any Help ?